# JavaScript createElement with ID

Tags: javascript, json, createelement

I am creating a JavaScript array with 3 elements:

```
var employees =
    [
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
        {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    ]
```

I want to use a `for` loop to loop through the data. Here is the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
```

I want to create a new `<p>` for each object and place the data in the new `<p>`. I believe that I need to assign an id to each `<p>`. How would I achieve this?

Complete code thus far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>JSON Java Syntax Examples</h2>
<!--        <p id="demo"></p>-->

        <script>
            var employees =
                [
                    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
                    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
                    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
                ]

            for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
                {
                    document.createElement("p");
                    document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName;
                }
//            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = employees[0].firstName + " " + employees[0].lastName;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: var _el;for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++){ _el = document.createElement("p"); _el.innerHTML = employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName; document.getElementById("myList"). appendChild(_el)}

Comment: "I believe that I need to assign an id to each <p>". No there's no requirement to have an id on an element.

Comment: Do you have any plans to access your employee data after it have been rendered, like bring up more info, or edit the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `int` by `var` in for loop definition.
2. Assign new element to variable, e.g `new_p`.
3. Use `textContent()` function to set text content to your element.
4. Finally append the new paragraph `new_p` to your body using `appendChild()` function.

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
var employees =
    [
      {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
      {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
      {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
    ]

for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
{
    var new_p = document.createElement("p");

    new_p.textContent = employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName;

    document.body.appendChild(new_p);
}
```

Comment: I had already changed the int to var. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: Awesome, this is slightly different to my final code but works 100%. I have accepted as the answer!

Comment: But there is now no need to assign an ID (actually there never was).

Comment: IE8 compatibility is no longer something considered worthy of special note. In the very near future, this will also become true of IE9 and IE10. If is was required to mention IE8 compatibility issues, nearly every answer on SO would have to mention it. Instead, just consider that every answer at the bottom, saying "May not work on old unsupported browsers".

Comment: The title of the post was based on the OP's incorrect understanding that he need an ID to start with.

Comment: @torazaburo Do you mean that everyone should _imagine_ that it at the bottom of every answer says "May not work on old unsupported browsers"? .. or should one when answer, not mention any particular browser but just write "May not work on old unsupported browsers"?

Comment: @LGSon I meant "imagine".

Comment: @torazaburo Then I agree when it comes to older browsers in average. When talking about a particular feature which exists _only_ on IE8 (and normally lower), I disagree. In most reports IE8 usage is bigger than IE9 and 10 together, over 10% in some cases (like in [this report](http://www.upsdell.com/BrowserNews/stat_trends.htm)), so in cases like this, I can't see how mention IE8 would be considered not worthy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after reading the comments and answers here and doing some more research I have found the solution and it works 100%. I am not assigning an ID to any of the newly created elements. I am using `innerHTML` to add the data to the element and then using `appendChild` to add the tag to the document.

Here is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>JSON Java Syntax Examples</h2>

            <script>
                var employees =
                    [
                        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
                        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
                        {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
                    ]

                for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
                    {
                        var p = document.createElement("p");
                        p.innerHTML = employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName;
                        document.body.appendChild(p);
                    }
    //            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = employees[0].firstName + " " + employees[0].lastName;
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: You don't have any HTML content why are you using `innerHTML`? use `textContent` instead in case of text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern approach:

First, define a function to create a DOM document fragment, based on an array of elements. A DOM fragment can be built up and inserted into the DOM all at once. In a simple example, it wouldn't make any difference, but it would be faster if there were a lot of DOM manipulations going on.

```
function createFragment(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(r, e) {
    r.appendChild(e);
    return r;
  }, document.createDocumentFragment());
}
```

Write the function to transform a particular employee's data into a `p` element:

```
function makeElt(emp) {
  var text = document.createTextNode(emp.firstName + ' ' + emp.lastName);
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(text);
  return p;
}
```

With these pieces in place, we need only to write:

```
document.body .                 // To the document body,
  appendChild (                 // append
    createFragment (            // the fragment containing
      employees .               // all of the employees
        map (                   // transformed into
          makeElt               // a DOM element
)));
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Below code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++)
            {
                var pObj = document.createElement("p");
        var t = document.createTextNode(employees[i].firstName + " " + employees[i].lastName); 
                pObj.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(pObj); 
            }
```

Comment: How does the paragraph get attached to the document?